# Cannot understand exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

Tags: shell, tcl

I am editing my question. Before starting the PERL/tcl script i saw the following

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect
```

I didn't get what "exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}" this means. This is tcl script. Same thing i noticed in PERL too.

Comment: Please make sure you are not trying to interpret a `bash` command entered at the shell command prompt instead.

Comment: I think i is trying to launch Jwish shell but dont know what ${1+$@} is  doing

Comment: Thanks. Do consider looking up bash variables online to figure this out.

Comment: What this have to do with Perl?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `${1:+$@}`?

Comment: @M42 : I took this from perl. ./Jwish is bash command but argument is perl argument

Comment: @Nitesh it might be handy, then, to provide a little bit of the rest of the script so that there is more information about those variables.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: May be u r right. Please let me know what is that

Comment: It is reasonable to close this as a duplicate, but it is definitely a real question (although in its pre-edited form it is not a real question). This is an 'exec hack' and is used in place of a `#!` line.  It is from before the days when `#!/usr/bin/env` could be used, and is more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell, `$1` is the first argument and `$@` are all the arguments. `${FOO+BAR}` means "if $FOO is set, use BAR.

So `${1+$@}` means "all the arguments, if the first argument is set". But that is redundant, isn't it?

The Portable Shell Programming section of the GNU Autoconf manual says, in [Shell Substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Shell-Substitutions.html#Shell-Substitutions):

> One of the most famous shell-portability issues is related to ‘"$@"’. When there are no positional arguments, Posix says that ‘"$@"’ is supposed to be equivalent to nothing, but the original Unix version 7 Bourne shell treated it as equivalent to ‘""’ instead, [... a long discussion of the gory details ...]

But this only makes sense if double quotes are used. Here they seem to be left off by accident.

Comment: Probably accidentally omitted when transcribing into the question; new questioners often find it hard to really believe that cut-n-paste is superior for accuracy than just typing it all out by hand. (This can sometimes make understanding the error messages they're talking about _very_ hard indeed…)